# I want to export current database from server by CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to export current database from server by Program  .Is any cakephp code is there ?
My database in mysql

Comment: My database contains several tables.. each one hour we manually exporting the database ...in case of that any plugin there in cakephp

Comment: Export **to what**? CSV? SQL? XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the cake console you simply do:

```
cake schema dump -write dump.slq
```

And if you want it to be database agnostic schema you can use:

```
cake schema generate
```

And restore the db:

```
cake schema create
```

I like to use 'cake schema generate' to keep snapshots of my database schema under version control.

Comment: Thanks Lot ... New thing i got

Answer (score 2):

add this to your crontab

```
1 * * * * mysqldump -u <username> -p<password> --databases <database_name> /home/<nix_username>/dump_`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`
```